# How can I display Total Supply and Circulating Supply for SPL token(Solana based token) on CMC and CG?

Tags: endpoint, solana

I want to write an API endpoint to display TOTAL SUPPLY and Circulating Supply for SPL-token as a numerical value.
SPL tokens are fungible tokens on the Solana Blockchain.
But I only have an example for ETH.
Looking forward to solving this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total supply directly through: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettokensupply

Circulating supply is a bit trickier, and depends on whether or not you freeze tokens.  For that, you need to:

- get all of the token accounts for your mint using `getProgramAccounts` https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getprogramaccounts, which a nice example at https://solanacookbook.com/references/accounts.html#get-program-accounts
- iterate through the parsed program accounts, and subtract any frozen tokens from the total supply

Or you can add any other specific logic needed for your circulating supply.